# Dynamically change feature image in customiser

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, theme-customizer

For this client's Website I am making on their homepage there is a section called featured products with images showing off the product. Currently I have to update these images manually through my `front-page.php` file but I don't want the client to have to do this, I need a custom section in the customiser called something like `featureImages` and here he can upload his own image that then updates on the front-page. There would have to be 4 upload sections like:

`featureImage-1` `featureImage-2` `featureImage-3` `featureImage-4`

Then when he uploads a file to either one of them it replaces the currently one with the one he has. I've seen this on some themes but I just don't know how they do it.

I've tried searching for this but I don't really know how to put it into words for Google to give me a result.

I apprentice any help or if you could point me in the right direction if this has been asked before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customizer has a [special control for file uploads](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Upload_Control). Assuming that you already know how the theme customizer works, you would have to add four controls in this fashion:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'wpse215632_image_1', 
    array(
        'label'       => __( 'First image', 'wpse215632_theme' ),
        'description' => __( 'More about first image', 'wpse215632_theme' ),
        'section'     => 'wpse215632__section_id',
        'settings'    => 'wpse215632__setting_id',
    ) ) 
);
```

Now, you can retrieve the image in your template with `get_theme_mod('wpse215632_image_1')`.

Comment: my small contribution to lower the unanswered rate ;)

Comment: @MarkKaplun wait I thought that started Saturday? Is someone getting ahead of their self ;)